# Delete All Emails in a Highrise App

Tags: highrise

How do I delete all the emails in my [highrise](http://highrisehq.com/) app? I don't want to delete the entire thing and start over, I've got companies and tags and metadata. What's the easiest way?

This question paraphrased from [Tibor Holoda](http://getsatisfaction.com/people/tiborholoda)'s [question](http://getsatisfaction.com/37signals/topics/can_you_help_me_deleting_all_emails_and_start_again_please) on [GetSatisfaction](http://getsatisfaction.com)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is available through the [API](http://developer.37signals.com/highrise), and should be easy with the [ruby bindings](http://developer.37signals.com/highrise/highrise.rb):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
ENV['SITE'] = "http://passkey:X@my.hirisehq.com"
require 'highrise'
Highrise::Person.each do |person|
  person.emails.each {|email|
    email.destroy
  }
end
```